# How much do I pay?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Is it correct to say 'how much do we pay' when asking for a bill in the restaurant? Does it sound ok?

Comment: Can you explain why you are concerned about this phrase. For example  has someone told you that it is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 'How much do we pay?'

**is definitely grammatically correct, and entirely understandable.**

---

But it's not terribly idiomatic, that is to say, it's not a phrasing that a native speaker would use.

More natural phrasings would be:

> 'How much do we owe?'
>
> 'What is the total?'
>
> 'How much did that cost?'

But in the very specific context of paying at the end of a sit-down meal, a native speaker would overwhelmingly ask:

> 'Can I get the bill, please?'

or

> 'Can we have the bill?'

or even just

> 'Bill, please?'

(In the US, I believe `check` is used instead of `bill`?)

Answer (score 0):

That's absolutely *fine!* Because you are talking about *money* and in this context, it's not countable. Uncountable nouns with no definite *quantity* take *much* opposite to *many*.

> How *much* do we pay for this?

On the other hand, if the concern is *not money* but precisely dollars, then you ask...

> How *many* dollars do we pay for this?

Comment: I agree that the latter is grammatically sound, but I think it's almost inconceivable that a native speaker would use that phrasing, except is the most contrived of circumstances.

Comment: If you want to pay for a meal the usual request is: *May I/we have the bill? Or: *Would you bring the bill? You might ask *How much do we pay* or *How much would be pay?* when you are seeking the price of a service. If it's just an item, you would ask: *What's the price?* or *What (how much) does it cost?) This has to do with idiom rather than grammar.

Answer (score 0):

> 'how much do we pay'

Is grammatically correct, but not what you would normally say. You would normally say something like (UK English)

> May I have the bill please?